# Implement Seek on /dev/stdin file descriptor in Rust

Tags: file, rust, trait

Problem: In order to be able to use the `arrow` crate's [`infer_file_schema`](https://docs.rs/arrow-csv/34.0.0/arrow_csv/reader/fn.infer_file_schema.html) function with input piped to `/dev/stdin`, I need to manually implement the `Seek` trait on a Reader, as it doesn't exist for piped `/dev/stdin/` by default.

The function that uses that Reader reads `n` lines, infers the schema from these `n` lines, then seeks back to the start of the "file".

So I don't need to buffer more than these `n` lines.

This is what I wrote:

```rust
struct SeekableReader<R: std::io::Read> {
    inner: R,           // underlying reader
    buffer: Vec<u8>,    // buffer for the first n lines
    buffer_size: usize, // size of the buffer in bytes
    pos: usize,         // current position in the buffer
    seekable: bool,     // whether seek is still possible
}

const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 8192;
impl<R: std::io::Read> SeekableReader<R> {
    fn new(reader: R, lines_to_buffer: Option<usize>) -> Self {
        let mut inner = reader;
        let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(BUFFER_SIZE);
        let mut lines = 0;
        let mut bytes_read = 0;
        let mut bytes_before;
        loop {
            bytes_before = bytes_read;
            buffer.append(&mut vec![0; BUFFER_SIZE - (buffer.len() - bytes_read)]);
            bytes_read += inner
                .read(&mut buffer[bytes_read..bytes_read + BUFFER_SIZE])
                .unwrap();
            lines += buffer[bytes_before..bytes_read]
                .iter()
                .filter(|&&x| x == 10)
                .count();
            if let Some(lines_to_buffer) = lines_to_buffer {
                // +1 because there may be a header
                if lines > lines_to_buffer + 1 {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if bytes_read == 0 {
                break;
            }
        }
        SeekableReader {
            inner,
            buffer,
            buffer_size: bytes_read,
            pos: 0,
            seekable: true,
        }
    }
}

impl<R: std::io::Read> std::io::Read for SeekableReader<R> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
        let buf_len = buf.len();
        if self.pos < self.buffer_size {
            if self.buffer_size - self.pos < buf_len {
                buf[..self.buffer_size - self.pos]
                    .copy_from_slice(&self.buffer[self.pos..self.buffer_size]);
                let len_read = self.buffer_size - self.pos;
                self.pos = self.buffer_size;
                Ok(len_read)
            } else {
                buf.copy_from_slice(&self.buffer[self.pos..self.pos + buf_len]);
                self.pos += buf_len;
                Ok(buf_len)
            }
        } else {
            self.seekable = false;
            self.inner.read(buf)
        }
    }
}

impl<R: std::io::Read> std::io::Seek for SeekableReader<R> {
    fn seek(&mut self, pos: SeekFrom) -> Result<u64, std::io::Error> {
        let error = Err(std::io::Error::new(
            std::io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
            "Seeking outside of buffer, please report to https://github.com/domoritz/arrow-tools/issues/new".to_string(),
        ));
        if self.seekable {
            match pos {
                SeekFrom::Start(pos) => {
                    if pos >= self.buffer_size as u64 {
                        error
                    } else {
                        self.pos = pos as usize;
                        Ok(pos)
                    }
                }
                SeekFrom::Current(pos) => {
                    let new_pos = self.pos as i64 + pos;
                    if 0 <= new_pos && new_pos < self.buffer_size as i64 {
                        self.pos = new_pos as usize;
                        Ok(new_pos as u64)
                    } else {
                        error
                    }
                }
                SeekFrom::End(_) => error,
            }
        } else {
            error
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this struct in action here: https://github.com/domoritz/arrow-tools/pull/10/files

Answer (score 2):

I think you could adopt a simpler approach.

1. Instead of using `infer_file_schema` use `infer_reader_schema` which doesn't require `Seek`.
2. Wrap the `File` in a `Tee` struct that stores copies of everything read from the file in a `Vec<u8>`.
3. `.chain()` that buffer and the file after inferring the schema to get the whole file.

Let's look at your current code:

```
struct SeekableReader<R: std::io::Read> {
```

The convention in Rust is typically to avoid putting restrictions on the `struct` itself.

```
    inner: R,           // underlying reader
    buffer: Vec<u8>,    // buffer for the first n lines
    buffer_size: usize, // size of the buffer in bytes
```

A `Vec` already has both a capacity and length. It seems suspect that you need another one.

```
    pos: usize,         // current position in the buffer
    seekable: bool,     // whether seek is still possible
}

const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 8192;
impl<R: std::io::Read> SeekableReader<R> {
    fn new(reader: R, lines_to_buffer: Option<usize>) -> Self {
        let mut inner = reader;
        let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(BUFFER_SIZE);
```

It might be an idea to consider using `BufReader` and call its `read_until` method several times to get each line, use `buffer` to pull out the remaining buffer, and then `into_inner` to get back the original file.

```
        let mut lines = 0;
        let mut bytes_read = 0;
        let mut bytes_before;
```

Just `let` the bytes_before be in the loop. There's no reason to have it outside of the loop.

```
        loop {
            bytes_before = bytes_read;
            buffer.append(&mut vec![0; BUFFER_SIZE - (buffer.len() - bytes_read)]);
            bytes_read += inner
                .read(&mut buffer[bytes_read..bytes_read + BUFFER_SIZE])
                .unwrap();
            lines += buffer[bytes_before..bytes_read]
                .iter()
                .filter(|&&x| x == 10)
                .count();
            if let Some(lines_to_buffer) = lines_to_buffer {
                // +1 because there may be a header
                if lines > lines_to_buffer + 1 {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if bytes_read == 0 {
                break;
            }
```

I think this is incorrect, because it looks at the total bytes read. I think you need to look at the bytes read in the last invocation of `read` to determine if that was zero and thus there is nothing more to read.

```
        }
        SeekableReader {
            inner,
            buffer,
            buffer_size: bytes_read,
            pos: 0,
            seekable: true,
        }
    }
}

impl<R: std::io::Read> std::io::Read for SeekableReader<R> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
```

You could simplify your implementation if you put the buffer you assembled in a `std::io::Cursor`. Basically, you should be able to read from the cursor, and if it returns nothing, then you can read from the file.

```
        let buf_len = buf.len();
```

I'm not sure why you copy the length like this.

```
        if self.pos < self.buffer_size {
            if self.buffer_size - self.pos < buf_len {
                buf[..self.buffer_size - self.pos]
                    .copy_from_slice(&self.buffer[self.pos..self.buffer_size]);
                let len_read = self.buffer_size - self.pos;
                self.pos = self.buffer_size;
                Ok(len_read)
            } else {
                buf.copy_from_slice(&self.buffer[self.pos..self.pos + buf_len]);
                self.pos += buf_len;
                Ok(buf_len)
            }
```

I think you should be able to construct `len_read` as the minimum of the buffer length and the remaining bytes and then combine these two cases.

```
        } else {
            self.seekable = false;
            self.inner.read(buf)
        }
    }
}

impl<R: std::io::Read> std::io::Seek for SeekableReader<R> {
    fn seek(&mut self, pos: SeekFrom) -> Result<u64, std::io::Error> {
        let error = Err(std::io::Error::new(
            std::io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
            "Seeking outside of buffer, please report to https://github.com/domoritz/arrow-tools/issues/new".to_string(),
        ));
```

It's a little odd to build an error and then usually not return it. Especially true since this allocates by constructing a String. Probably Rust optimizes that out though. Nevertheless, I'd move it to a function or something to build the error and call it in the right places.

```
        if self.seekable {
            match pos {
```

It seems to me that in practice, you only need to support the narrow case of seeking back to the start of the file. So I'd just support that precise case.

```
                SeekFrom::Start(pos) => {
                    if pos >= self.buffer_size as u64 {
                        error
                    } else {
                        self.pos = pos as usize;
                        Ok(pos)
                    }
                }
                SeekFrom::Current(pos) => {
                    let new_pos = self.pos as i64 + pos;
                    if 0 <= new_pos && new_pos < self.buffer_size as i64 {
                        self.pos = new_pos as usize;
                        Ok(new_pos as u64)
                    } else {
                        error
                    }
                }
                SeekFrom::End(_) => error,
            }
        } else {
            error
        }
    }
}
```